# Is there a way to set a global testing date in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have a PHP project which I need to test for a datetime other than the current one (i.e. right now). In other words I need any datetime functions to return a datetime that I set. I am using the Laravel framework which ships with the [nesbot/carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) package. Carbon allows you to set a test datetime with the `Carbon::setTestNow()` method.

#### Example

This tells the `Carbon::now()` method to return `04/19/2005 11:35:00` as the current datetime.

```php
$date = Carbon::parse('4/19/05 11:35');
Carbon::setTestNow($date);
```

Unfortunately, I have only been able to get it to work within the scope of a script or method. As I said before, I would like to set a global test datetime.

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to achieve if setTestNow() is not fitting

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski have elaborated on this question, is there any way I can get insight into the review process for re-opening?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I know it's been awhile, but any chance we could get this re-opened? I'd rather not duplicate this question and it seems like this ability would be incredibly useful for developers (like myself) who have to build applications with specific criteria for certain dates.

Comment: This one is just old so many things could be just outdated, so if you still got this problem not resolved, feel free to post new question - it's nothing wrong about it.

Comment: OK, I thought the goal was to not duplicate questions on this site

Answer (score 2):

PHP-FIG proposes (since November 2022) a standard way to mock the time in PHP:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-20/

Ideally libraries, frameworks and your own app should provide, implement it, and always use this mockable `now()` instead of using directly `time()` or `new DateTime()` then you can mock only the clock service in test and have them all in sync.

Else, you'll have to use one of the various available work-arounds, among other you can check `symfony/phpunit-bridge` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#time-sensitive-tests

It uses a namespace trick to replace `time()` (and other now-related functions/classes) with a frozen one.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that this is a Carbon only solution not a global PHP solution.**

The simplest way to do this for Carbon is to set a global variable of some sort  to a date or datetime string and override certain base Carbon methods to return results based on that date. Examples of the methods to override would be `now()`, `today()`, `yesterday()` and `tomorrow()`. You should probably also override `parse()` since it will return the current datetime if an empty value is passed in.

Here's an example of what I did with `config('app.test_date')` being the date I'm using in place of "today".

```php
class MyCarbon extends \Carbon\Carbon
{
    public static function now($tz = null) {
        if (config('app.env') != 'production' && !empty(config('app.test_date'))) {
            return parent::parse(config('app.test_date'), $tz);
        }

        return parent::now($tz);
    }
}
```

This solution works well enough as long as you don't use the Laravel `now()`, `today()`, etc. helper methods.